# Audio quality recording

Tags: recording, audio-editing

My audio interface and DAW support recording at 96khz / 24 bit. When I export a video from Magix there's no option for 24 bit for sound (highest option is 48khz / 16 bit). When I checked the recommended audio for YouTube high quality they say 44.1khz / 24 bit. Will this change much in the audio quality if I export at 16 bit instead of 24? I couldn't hear a difference myself...

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85212/is-cd-audio-quality-good-enough-for-the-final-delivery-of-music

Comment: Are you using Magix as your DAW, or just to get a video so you can upload to Youtube?

Comment: The difference will be small and by the time its on YT maybe you can't hear it, but there will be a difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not get along with 48kHz and 16bit *after* proper mastering, you are doing something likely unsuited for human consumption.

24bit is for having large dynamic reserves for recording and mixing, 96kHz is for having good reserves for non-linear manipulations and good properties for digital filtering.  The finished product should not require those reserves any more.